# I want to know if there are any tools that can search for 全称s

Tags: vocabulary

I need a searching tool which satisfies the following condition.

1. As keyword is inputted then a corresponding 全称 is displayed in an output.

E.g. 初中　⇒ 初级中学

I think that it is so hard for ones to memorize  abbreviated Chinese vocabs without knowing 全称s in general.

Do you have some recommendations?

Comment: Can you read Chinese-Chinese dictionaries? For example in 现代汉语词典 the explanation for 初中 is "初级中学的简称". Similarly for other abbreviations.

Comment: You could ask ChatGPT.  (It says: Yes, "初中" (chūzhōng) is short for "初级中学" (chūjí zhōngxué), which translates to "junior high school" or "middle school.)  But I feel the main difficulty would be recognizing 简称.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Pleco dictionary.  I am sure it is not the only electronic dictionary to offer it, I believe it has what you need.

It lists 初中 as the abbreviation of 初級中學
as its own entry,  simply searching the word abbreviation lists many such abbreviations like 工 for engineer, and you can perform searches using * aka if you are having trouble finding results for something cause the portion you have isn't the first character it will still show under asterisks.

Hope this helps o(∩_∩)o